# Using UINavigationController in Tab bar application in ios 6

Tags: ios6, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.5

I'm developing an Tab bar application in that i want to use navigation controller.
In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` i want to push the new view to the controller. I tried the following code but it did'nt help me.

```
DetailView *detailView = [[DetailView alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

Can any one guide me where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if there is no parent UINavigationController you can create one and call it like this.

```
DetailView *detailView = [[DetailView alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myCont];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Called on Completion");
}];
```

If you already have a UINavigationController just call it with

```
[self presentViewController:detailView animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Called on Completion");
}];
```